# How to disconnect/unregister a device from Twilio?

Tags: ios, twilio

For some reason, my app is still receiving incoming calls after I call `disconnectAll()` and set the device to nill.

What is the recommended way to unregister a device from Twilio? It looks like the JavaScript sdk has `destroy()`, but what is the iOS equivalent to this?

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation, it looks like there is a method [disconnectAll](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/tcdevice#disconnectAll) which disconnects itself from all connections, though android has a clean function [release](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/device#release__).

**Documentation:**

> -(void)disconnectAll
>
> Disconnect all current connections associated with the receiver.
>
> This a convenience routine that disconnects all current incoming and
>   outgoing connections.

Comment: This was my first guess too. But it doesn't work as expected given the lack of a destroy() or release(). It actually appears to behave just method by the same name in the javascript sdk:                            **Documentation:** `.disconnectAll()

Terminates the active connection. This will trigger the disconnect event handler. It will not prevent new incoming connections` I tested this by printing the devices capabilities before and after calling disconnectAll(); nothing changed. Moreover, the device was still able to make and receive calls.

Comment: You must contact twilio support members and ask about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can [call `unlisten` on a `TCDevice` object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/tcdevice#unlisten) which will stop it listening for incoming connections.

I'm not entirely sure how you'd actually destroy the object though (I'm still learning iOS dev myself right now).